# NuGet: remote server returned an Error(403) Forbidden

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

Whenever i attempt to install a package i get this error

```
remote server returned an Error(403) Forbidden
```

I can use other commands, such as get-package -ListAvailable, and discover whether there are any updates for installed packages but cannot actually install anything via Nuget.

This is the same for the command line and the package manager GUI.

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010.

I'm in a corporate environment too, which i suspect is the chief issue.

Any possible pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TFS? It seems to cause weird problems, there's info in the forums about removing a DLL to workaround it:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/246381

If it's not that - is it possible you have a proxy that NuGet isn't authenticating with properly? There's an issue in the bugtracker about this:

http://nupack.codeplex.com/workitem/231

Looks like it may have been fixed recently (though not sure if it's made it into a released build yet).

Failing that, could you capture the exact request with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and post details here?

Comment: Not using TFS. I suspect it's to do with the fact that every download gets routed through a scanner that blocks certain types of downloads.

Comment: I'll accept the second one as the answer since it's gone away since i updated to Nuget 1.4

Answer (score 8):

I have similar issue. I am using Visual Studio 2019. The problem started when I change my system password.

Sometimes clearing Nuget caches solve the issue.

`In VS, Go to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Click on Clear All NuGet Caches(s)`

If that does not solve the issue, then follow below steps.

Reset Nuget artifactory can resolve the issue. The way I resolved is as following:

If Control Panel is in `Icon (Large or Small) mode`

`Go to Control Panel > Credential Manager > Click on Windows Credentials`

If Control Panel is in `Category mode`

`Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Click on Windows Credentials`

On the expanded part find all nodes with `VSCredentials_` prefix > Click on it > Click on Edit button > Update your current system password.

Restart all Visual Studio instances and clear temp files (`C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp`).

Comment: finally! thank you so much. The point of the credentials helped me, because VS saves the credentials for artifactory in its own entry. and Git saves it in a separate own entry. I changed only the git entry, but now I scrolled down in the list and found the `VSCredentials_artifacts` entry, which was not updated after I changed the system password.

Comment: Thank you! The Credentials Manager cleanup saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this discussion:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/254328

and the solution i used:

http://blog.rthand.com/post/2011/08/26/Fixing-combination-of-NuGet-and-Team-Foundation-in-workgroup-configuration-401-Unauthorized.aspx

Comment: Thanks, The problem seems to have magically disappeared since i updated to Nuget 1.4, but it never was a TFS issue anyway.

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the company I worked for was blocking https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/dev12/extension.svc.
When they unblocked it the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem cropped up with me when I was upgrading my application for the .Net Framework 4.5.2. The application was an old one, using TFS 2010, and so the answer surprised me. First I got in touch with NuGet Support via email on the NuGet website. I was surprised how quickly they replied. 
They referred me to this link.

http://www.xavierdecoster.com/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore

It didn't look like it had the solution, but I found it did. My NuGet configuration was out of date and I had to change it.