# Nuget Server returning 403's and 404's

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I'm trying to host [nuget](/questions/tagged/nuget) on my Amazon EC2 VPS, and I'm having issues.

1. I've followed the instructions here ( [Hosting your own NuGet Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) )
2. I've read this thread ( [NuGet: remote server returned an Error(403) Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110478/nuget-remote-server-returned-an-error403-forbidden) ) along the same lines.

   1. I'm not running TFS
   2. It "could" be a proxy issue, but I'm not entirely sure how to check.

My NuGet feed is located at http://nuget.infinitas.ws. You'll notice that both http://nuget.infinitas.ws/nuget/Packages and http://nuget.infinitas.ws/Packages are throwing errors.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I abandoned it (for now), so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running the NuGet.Server in a Web Site-project. Try to run it via an ASP.NET Web Application instead (in Visual Studio you can create one via File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Application)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest version (1.5)?

The [release notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.5) include some changes related to proxy authentication:

> #### Support for Proxies that require authentication
>
> When using NuGet behind a proxy that requires authentication, NuGet will now prompt for proxy credentials. Entering credentials allows NuGet to connect to the remote repository.

Comment: yeah, I'm running the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party but I've just spent a frustrating couple of hours with the same problem.

I found that switching the Application Pool from "Classic" to "Integrated" fixed the problem